# Sum of several columns from a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

So say I have the following table:

```
In [2]: df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,2,3], 'b':[2,4,6], 'c':[1,1,1]})

In [3]: df
Out[3]: 
   a  b  c
0  1  2  1
1  2  4  1
2  3  6  1
```

I can sum a and b that way:

```
In [4]: sum(df['a']) + sum(df['b'])
Out[4]: 18
```

However this is not very convenient for larger dataframe, where you have to sum multiple columns together.

Is there a neater way to sum columns (similar to the below)? What if I want to sum the entire DataFrame without specifying the columns?

```
In [4]: sum(df[['a', 'b']]) #that will not work!
Out[4]: 18
In [4]: sum(df) #that will not work!
Out[4]: 21
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I think you can use double `sum` - first [`DataFrame.sum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html) create `Series` of sums and second [`Series.sum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.sum.html) get sum of `Series`:

```
print (df[['a','b']].sum())
a     6
b    12
dtype: int64

print (df[['a','b']].sum().sum())
18
```

You can also use:

```
print (df[['a','b']].sum(axis=1))
0    3
1    6
2    9
dtype: int64

print (df[['a','b']].sum(axis=1).sum())
18
```

Thank you [pirSquared](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40116219/sum-of-several-columns-from-a-pandas-dataframe/40116249?noredirect=1#comment67506082_40116249) for another solution - convert `df` to `numpy array` by [`values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.values.html) and then `sum`:

```
print (df[['a','b']].values.sum())
18
```

---

```
print (df.sum().sum())
21
```

Comment: also `df[['a', 'b']].values.sum()`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are looking something like this:

```
df["result"] = df.apply(lambda row: row['a' : 'c'].sum(),axis=1)
```