# Create calculated column of sum values of other columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with about 60 columns and the following structure:

```
    A    B  C           Y
0   12   1  0           1
1   13   1  0   [....]  0
2   14   0  1           1
3   15   1  0           0    
4   16   0  1           1
```

I want to create a zth column which will be the sum of the values from columns B to Y.

How can I proceed?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sum of several columns from a pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40116219/sum-of-several-columns-from-a-pandas-dataframe)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To create a copy of the dataframe while including a new column, use `assign`

```
df.assign(Z=df.loc[:, 'B':'Y'].sum(1))

    A  B  C  Y  Z
0  12  1  0  1  2
1  13  1  0  0  1
2  14  0  1  1  2
3  15  1  0  0  1
4  16  0  1  1  2
```

---

To assign it to the same dataframe, in place, use

```
df['Z'] = df.loc[:, 'B':'Y'].sum(1)
df

    A  B  C  Y  Z
0  12  1  0  1  2
1  13  1  0  0  1
2  14  0  1  1  2
3  15  1  0  0  1
4  16  0  1  1  2
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
   df['z']=df.iloc[:,1:].sum(1)
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me. I was hoping I could get an explanation why?

Comment: @Joe your first column dtype can be object , also , iloc is slice the data frame by position 1: in here means sleet the column from second column

Answer (score 2):

You could

```
In [2361]: df.assign(Z=df.loc[:, 'B':'Y'].sum(1))
Out[2361]:
    A  B  C  Y  Z
0  12  1  0  1  2
1  13  1  0  0  1
2  14  0  1  1  2
3  15  1  0  0  1
4  16  0  1  1  2
```